# Storing CoreData attributes as (Codable) Data rather than (NSCoding) Transformables

Tags: swift, core-data, nscoding, codable

I have arrays of simple structs that I would like to pack into a Core Data attribute. I don't need Core Data to handle each object independently, so packing into an array on one attribute seems fine and less overhead.

A complete solution might be to roll my own `NSValueTransformer`. I'd get full control over the process and storage. However, putting *more work* aside, since Swift 4 we now effectively have another approach to out-of-the-box serialization - storing objects as `Data` attributes, serialized by Swift 4's `Codable` protocol and (say) the `JSONEncoder`/`JSONDecoder` implementations.  This would be an alternative to the more typical approach using a Transformable attribute serialized via the default `NSValueTransformer` under `NSCoding`.

An immediate advantage is not having to inherit from `NSObject` and conform to `NSCoding`, for what in my case are simple value types. This alone makes me want to start using `Codable` as my default approach. Clearly, using the JSON encoder would mean conversion and representation of data under `utf8`, even if Core Data/sqlite see this as `Data`/BLOBs.  However from what I gather the default transformer to the (binary) plist format isn't exactly the most efficient, either.

Has anyone else taken this approach or otherwise know whether there may be any significant drawbacks or implications involved I’ve not considered? In short, could this be a reasonable approach?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you still are looking for a solution to this issue, but here is an overview of a solution that I use.  Assuming that `aStruct: Codable`, you can use this strategy.

In the core data model, I create a property such as `encodedStructArray` of type data for the desired entity.

Then in a swift extension for that entity, I create a computed read-write var with normal swift type:

```
    var structArray: [aStruct] {
        get {
            guard let data = encodedStructArray else { return [] }
            guard let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([aStruct].self, from: data) else { return [] }
            return result
        }
        set {
            encodedStructArray = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
        }
    }
```

Now you can use the var just like you would anywhere but for performance reasons, pull it out and use that rather than using the var directly in multiple places since this example does not cache the value.

If you wish to cache the result, you would need to add a transient to the data model with the name `structArray` of undefined type and hold the cache value in its primitive.  See the Core Data docs for an example.

Comment: After doing some performance testing, where my swift struct was some dates, some strings and a dictionary of `[String:Date]`, PropertyListEncoder/Decoder was consistently about 16% faster...  this may be the result of JSON date handling but it is something to keep in mind.